# Windows Batch Script - Extracting json value to variable using jq

Tags: json, batch-file, jq

I have a json response in a variable called %VM% defined by

```
set "myComm=curl "https://urlpath" -H "authorization:Bearer %Token%" -X GET"
For /F "delims=" %%G In ('%myComm%') Do Set VM=%%G
```

Echoing %VM% shows a json string like:

```
{"notes":"SVR Pro 123263","osType":"Windows","size":"Std","environment":"someTxtHere"}
```

I am doing the following

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ("%VM% | jq .environment") Do Set environment=%%a
```

if i then do:

```
echo %environment% >> debug.txt
echo "%environment%" >> debug.txt
```

On the first echo, it shows the correct json object for 'environment'- just the string of text in that json object. However, if I do the echo on the %environment% variable but surround it with double quotes it shows the full json response (i.e. its the same content as %VM%) not just the text of the json 'environment' object.

How can that be?

The problem its causing is with a later IF statement in the batch file:

```
if "%environment%"=="someTextEnvName" (set etc...
```

On this IF, I have to enclose the %environment% variable in double quotes otherwise the bat file crashes out - but using the double quotes causes this comparison never to match, probably for what I've described is happening in the double quoted echo above.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ("%VM% | jq .environment") Do Set environment=%%a` does not look at all correct to me. Regardless of the fact you have not told us what the content of `%VM%` is or how that content was defined, that for loop would return the entire string as %%a, it will not return the result of a command! A command, if you read the output from `for /?` in a Command Prompt window, would be `For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%VM% ^| jq .environment') Do Set "environment=%%G"`. 'Commands' in single quotes, "strings" in doublequotes, _(unless `usebackq` is in operation, 'strings', \`commands\`)_.

Comment: Thanks @Compo, appreciated - You've definitely spotted the issue. I've tried changing the code to your suggestion but it doesnt like that For loop when its ran in a batch file "The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect" - I've added the details of how VM is derived.

Comment: Looks like the following fixed it - many thanks. 

              For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('"echo %VM%" ^| jq .environment') Do Set "environment=%%G"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67788464/windows-batch-script-extracting-json-value-to-variable-using-jq#comment119825200_67788464) by m_finn:

> Looks like the following fixed it […]. `For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('"echo %VM%" ^| jq .environment') Do Set "environment=%%G"`